# Making a custom linked list class -- need help implementing get method

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to make a custom linked list, so far I've figured out how to make the general structure and the two easiest methods (`insertFirst` and `deleteFirst`). The next thing I want to do is make a get method that takes the index of a link and then returns the string at that location. I don't have any index or address assigned to each link, so I don't see how to refer to a specific location in my linked list. I see that if I write `first.next` I get the second item, and `first.next.next` I get the third item.. But I need to figure out how to make my index parameter (the one passed into the get method) correlate with the proper location in my list. How can I do this?

Here's my code:

**Test code**:

```
 class LinkedListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        
        list.insertFirst("cat");
        list.insertFirst("dog");
        list.insertFirst("fish");
        list.insertFirst("cow");
        list.insertFirst("horse");
        list.insertFirst("pig");
        list.insertFirst("chicken");
        
        System.out.println(list.get(1));
        
    }
}
```

**My class**:

```
public class LinkedList
{
    private Link first;
    
    
    public LinkedList()
    {
        first = null;
    }
    
    public void insertFirst(String word)
    {
        Link link = new Link(word);
        link.next = first;
        first = link;
    }
    
    public String deleteFirst()
    {
        Link temp = first;
        first = first.next;
        return temp.toString();
    }
    
    public String get(int index)
    {
        // the following is just to show that I can access different links
        // by adding more .next's after first--- but i need a way to access
        // the correct link based on the index passed in
        
        // String second = first.next.item;
        String third = first.next.next.item;
        // String fourth= first.next.next.next.item
        
        return third;
    }
    
}



public class Link
{
    public String item;
    public Link next;
    
    
    //Link constructor
    public Link(String theItem)
    {
        item = theItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `get(0)` returns you the first element:

If you want to put this method inside `public class LinkedList:`

```
    public String get(int index)
    {
        assert( index >= 0 )
        Link current = this.first;
        while (index > 0) {
            index--;
            current = current.next;
            // Check to see if this is out of bounds of the links
            if (current == Null) {
                // Since you are returning a String, you can also return
                // some kind of a flag to say that the index is out of bounds
                return Null;
            }
        }
        return current.item;       
    }
```

Alternatively, you can also implement this inside `public class Link:`, but this is not advisable since it wastes space on your call stack:

```
    public String get(int index)
    {
        assert ( index >= 0 )
        if ( index == 0 ) {
            return this.item;
        } else {
            index--;
            if ( next == null ) {
                return Null;
            }
            return next.get(index)
        }
    }
```

and inside public class LinkedList:

```
    public String get(int index)
    {
         return first.get(index);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

LinkedList is supposed to have O(n) for finding the element.

So essentially what this means is that you need to keep doing element.next till you reach the nth index.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you are creating your own `LinkedList` class, you should name it as such rather than using the existing `LinkedList` class. So, rather you can use `MyLinkedList`

Second, you can't access the elements in the LinkedList by index. That is not how `LinkedList` works, or should work if you are creating your own. Rather you get them based on the value. So, you should pass the value to your `get` method, and iterate through your `LinkedList` to get the appropriate `Link` with the given value.

Answer (score 0):

### recursive

```
 public String get(int index)
        {
            assert index >= 0;
            return get(index, first);       
        }

 public String get(int index, Link cursor) {
         if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
         } else if (index == 0) {
            return cursor.toString();
         } else {
           return get(index-1, cursor.next);
         }
  }
```

### iterative

```
public String get(int index)
{
    assert index >= 0;
    Link cursor = first;
    while (index > 0) {
       if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        cursor = cursor.next;
        index--;
    }
    return cursor.toString();       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you with what you need:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/143089-linked-list-tutorial/